# Lock pattern screen in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am looking to create an application using Visual Studio C# that mimics the Android pattern lock screen, and was wondering if anyone had any experience in this or has any tips to guide me.

This is none commercial project, it is part of uni study project.

What i am trying to do is to have a grid of any size and try to draw a pattern over it, so each cell of the grid is regarded as one point of the pattern.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance,
HS

Comment: You could do this using screen coordinates and the mouseover event handler or equiv. in Windows Phone...

Comment: There is an answer here which might help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909176/android-lock-screen-c-sharp-net-replica

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am interested in developing a web application not mobile phone app.
I have already seen the answer you provided with thanks, but didn't work.

if anyone has the code to try I would be really grateful.

Regards